# SQLAlchemy: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect my flask application to my local MySQL database for testing. I've made a flask object and a class to represent an example table to be created after a successful connection.

These are my local env vars for my project:

```
#.env
LOCAL_MYSQL_URL = mysql://Username:somePassword@127.0.0.1:3306/database_name
```

This is my project_name `__init__` file:

```
#__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

ON_HEROKU = 'ON_HEROKU' in os.environ

if ON_HEROKU:
    DB_URL = os.environ.get('CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL')
else:
    DB_URL = os.environ.get('LOCAL_MYSQL_URL')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)  
db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

However I get the following error after running the app:

```
  if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I am trying to make this work following tutorials and answers contributed here on stackoverlow to similar questions, but none of them helped me out so far.

What am I missing here? What's wrong with my mysql driver name?

Comment: Does it raise a `KeyError` if you change this line: `DB_URL = os.environ.get('LOCAL_MYSQL_URL')` to `os.environ['LOCAL_MYSQL_URL']`?

Comment: @SuperShoot Yes. I've tried it out your way, and I get : `raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'MYSQL_URL'`

Comment: `'MYSQL_URL'` or `'LOCAL_MYSQL_URL'` in the `KeyError` message?

Comment: Sorry, I miscopied it. it is `'LOCAL_MYSQL_URL'` of course.

Comment: Well if `os.environ[...]` raises a key error, then the env var isn't set meaning `.env` file isn't getting loaded at runtime. For environment variables, if there isn't a default fallback value to use, I think it is better to use the dict index syntax (`[...]`) rather than `.get()` so that it fails early rather than set the variable to `None`.

Comment: "What's wrong with my mysql driver name?": `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'` means that `sa_url` is `None`, there's nothing wrong with the driver name, just that the url you are passing to flask-sqlalchemy is `None` and `None.drivername` doesn't exist.

Comment: @SuperShoot I'm not sure I understand. I've just removed any db.method() from the example code and printed out the DB_URL. It showed the `mysql://Username:somePassword@127.0.0.1:3306/database_name` string from the `.env` file. How can this be?

Comment: I have had to use pymysql to get this working. `pip install pymysql`

Comment: @cinch Thanks for the tip, but I it says I already had that lib.

Comment: @MattSom that is in direct conflict with your comment where you said that you get the key error accessing the env var without `.get()`. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: @SuperShoot Just tried it again. I do get a `KeyError` without the `.get()` and I do get the string from the `.env` file using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the SQLAlchemy URI resembles this format after `pip install pymysql`

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@localhost:3306/{DB_NAME}'
```

Comment: Strange. Why do I need the `+pymysql` driver? According to [the docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#connection-uri-format) I only need the mysql. I've tried it and I get the same error.

Comment: It is the mysql driver for Python 3. I think you're configuring the uri wrong. Try this ```app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/db_name'```

Comment: Wow, you are right! I've made a typo after your first suggestion, I wrote `+pymsql` instead of `+pymysql`. Tried again, now the database has the two rows! 
Thank you, kind sir! :)

Comment: This is crazy. Tried it again this morning and throws the same error. For the same code.

Comment: Okay, I know what was the problem. First I did not include pymysql driver as cicnh has suggested. On the other hand I did not even use the dotenv modul to read from the `.env` file. For some reason `os.environ.get()` did read the `.env` after it was created (I'm using VS Code), but this morning it had not. So use `dotenv` guys, don't let your development tool trick you.

Answer (score 0):

if you ever use "db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)" in your models.py you will still get the same error message.
So change the drivername mysqldb to pymysql as suggest by @MattSom and comment or delete
this instruction "db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)"